# Log output of method to pipeline to jenkins output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shared library of my own where a 3rd party java library gets 'grabed' and used more or less as follows:

```
package mypackage

@Grab(group='some.group', module='some-module', version = '1.0)
import some.group.some-module.Utils


@Singleton
class Grabber implements Serializable {


   def static void callExternalMethod(String params){
     Utils.method(params);  // I would like to see what this one prints to stdout
   }
}
```

The pipeline is more or less

```
@Library('mylibrary')
import mypackage.*

node{
  ...

  stage("run") {
      Grabber.callExternalMethod("some parameters")
  }
```

}

The `Grab` works and the method is called, but I would like to include what `Utils.method()` normally prints to stdout on the Jenkins build output.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you make the signature change to accept scrip as param for callExternalMethod then you can call `script.echo("your log")` to print to jenkins console and also pass the scrip as `Grabber.callExternalMethod("some parameters", this)` from jenkins file

Comment: @jos, I want to see what the `Utils.method` prints to stdout, not to pring something from the `callExternalMethod`. The `Utils.method` is from an external java library, not mine to modify